# Redirect api routes to a different subfolder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, virtualhost

My server has a frontend and a backend like this:

```
·
|__www
  |__frontend
     |__public
  |__backend
     |__public
```

And I would like to make all my routes point to the frontend except anything that has ***/api*** prefix.

For example:

```
domain.com/foo points to the frontend  
domain.com/api/foo points to the backend
```

I've tried with apache vhost and also with .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^api(/.*)?$ /backend/public$1 [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond ^ /frontend/public [L]
```

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need a rule to avoid both folders (`frontend` and `backend`) from being rewritten as well. Also, a `RewriteRule` is missing in your last rule.

```
RewriteEngine On

# Don't rewrite frontend nor backend
RewriteRule ^(frontend|backend)(/.*)?$ - [L,NC]

# /api/foo to /backend/public/foo
RewriteRule ^api(/.*)?$ /backend/public$1 [L,NC]

# not a file, /foo to /frontend/public/foo
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /frontend/public/$1 [L]
```

Comment: My vhost DocumentRoot points to /www and when I try to access domain.com or domain.com/foo, I should be having the frondend displayed, yet I have a 403 `you don't have permission to access / on this server`. I've checked all the file and folder rights.

Comment: I assumed a htaccess context when writing the rules (and by reading your question), although you mentioned both. Are you testing these rules from inside a vhost block?

Comment: No, the htaccess is in /www/.htaccess Should I write these runes inside the vhost?

Comment: No, it's fine within the htaccess. Are you able to display the content of a page directly from `domain.com/frontend/existing_page` ? The code above should work, there must be something else going on.